# IE doesn't show SVG

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, svg

the IE doesn't show SVG images on my website.

The first image that isn't shown is a logo image which is put via :before content in front of a Logofont.

the css code is the following:

```
    .logo-svg:before {
    content: url('images/logo.svg');
}

.logo-svg {
    height: 1.6em;
    width: 1.6em;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 0.2em;
    position: relative;
    top: 0.2em;
}
```

Then a few images, that are background images for icons are not shown too, the CSS is here:

```
.author-link-posts {
    background-image: url("/images/icons/svg/archive.svg") !important
}
```

Has somebody an idea why the IE doesn't show the SVG or maybe a workaround or something like this?

Regards,
Markus

Comment: You might have to say which version of Internet Explorer you are hoping to use. IE has been notoriously bad at supporting web standards, so you might find that most versions of IE cannot support the features you hope to use.

Comment: what version of ie are you targeting? ie since version 9 (4 years old at this point) has had some support for svg.

Comment: Which version of IE? Alse, see: http://caniuse.com/#feat=svg

Comment: Are you getting any errors in your browser console?  Are you sure that your SVG images are not 404ing?

Comment: IE has serious issues with scaling SVGs and will always display them as `0x0` unless defined otherwise. I know this to be true for `img` elements and I'm assuming `:pseudo` elements would have the same behaviours...

Comment: Does it show the images if you view them directly?

Comment: @somethinghere IE uses the default size for replaced elements (300x150) for SVG if width and height are not specified.

Comment: @hungerstar I am not sure about the specification, but I have had issues with this before. IE is a pain. If your SVG does not specify a width and height they turn out as 0x0, while other browsers scale them like image tags. Ah well.

Comment: Using a relative URL inside a CSS file is asking for trouble. Try changing `content: url('images/logo.svg');` to `content: url('/images/logo.svg');` (with a forward slash before `images`).

Comment: @somethinghere never seen 0x0 SVG in IE when width and height are not defined. I've only seen what the spec defines, 300x150. And I agree, IE is a pain! I hope [Microsoft Edge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Edge) is not more of the same. IE be gone forever!

Comment: @Sukrams do you have a `viewBox` defined for you SVGs?

Comment: @squeamishossifrage I have encountered it many times and just this morning I had to swap out an SVG logo for an image on Edge as it was rendering the color incorrectly. So... Thats not a good start.

Comment: Can you use VML as an alternative? I think it works back to IE5.

Comment: You can convert SVG to VML here: http://vectorconverter.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Hello,
sorry for the late answer, but I was a little bit busy and the project hasn't that priority for me...

I want to support from IE9+, but it doesn't work in IE10, IE11, Edge...
And I don't get any errors in the console and viewBox is defined.

What I tried is to link it with the forward slash.. that doesn't work, too.

Comment: Okay, so i checked it again. It was the ohne thing with the slash before the path... Now it works.

Answer (score 1):

SVG is not supported in IE8 and below. Is this issue happened in all other browsers? Also you can use [modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) as a fallback.

Basically Modernizr will add a "no-svg" class in  tag.

Comment: This should be a comment.

Answer (score 0):

The solution are the paths. I had to put the slash before the path, so it works in the IE.

Comment: Both paths, or just the `:before` one?

Comment: just the `:before` one